# Highcharts background options

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

How do I add background boxes in line chart using Highcharts?

Type : line chart

[image]

Comment: Use grid lines and minor grid lines http://jsfiddle.net/g26xwgzp/. See API for more options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minorGridLineWidth

Comment: Thanks Morgon. I tried with minorGridLineColor option but its displaying only yAxis line not x-axis. Fir x-axis i used gridLineWidth: 1 option but its displying horizontal line. but box width will be huge, its not satisfying my requirement. xAxis: { gridLineWidth: 1 }, yAxis: { minorGridLineColor: '#E0E0E0', minorGridLineWidth: 2, minorTickLength: 0, minorTickInterval: 'auto' }

Comment: You have to set minor grid lines for both axes - xAxis and yAxis. Look in the fiddle I posted in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this kind of background for chart's plot area by [enabling plot lines for both x](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth) and y axes.

```
xAxis:[{
    gridLineWidth: 1
}] // for yAxis grid lines are visible by default
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0md5s7cz/

Alternatively you could set an image for [background of a chart's plot area](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBackgroundImage).

```
chart: {
  plotBackgroundImage: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBTab.png'
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wLvu94s/1/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually i dont want to add background image. Using gridLineWidth options i tried but the size of the box is big.         Actually i am looking for small box which i shared in my attachment.

Comment: @rafik In that case please see the comment from **morganfree** under your question - minorGridLine should be the solution for you.

Comment: Thanks Kacper. I tried with minorGridLineColor option but its displaying only yAxis line not x-axis. Fir x-axis i used gridLineWidth: 1 option but its displying horizontal line. but box width will be huge, its not satisfying my requirement.  
    xAxis: {
               gridLineWidth: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            minorGridLineColor: '#E0E0E0',
           minorGridLineWidth: 2,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            minorTickInterval: 'auto'
        }

Comment: @rafik How about setting the same minorGridLine* options for the xAxis? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0md5s7cz/1/)